# XCFramework creation error: The CodingKeys(stringValue: "SupportedPlatform", intValue: nil) is empty in library -arm64_armv7

Tags: ios, xcframework

The iOS SDK I want to distribute is made up of a framework which has other frameworks in its Frameworks folder. I want to convert the outmost framework into an XCFramework for distribution. To do this, first I archive the framework with below commands:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme "MySDK" \
-destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
-archivePath ../output/MySDK-iOS \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
-workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace"

xcodebuild archive \
-scheme "MySDK" \
-destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
-archivePath ../output/MySDK-Sim \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
-workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace"
```

As a result, inside the Package Contents of the archive I see both inner frameworks and the main framework are created and listed under Products->Library->Frameworks. I attempt to create the xcframework with this command:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework ./MySDK-iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MySDK.framework \
-framework ./MySDK-Sim.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MySDK.framework \
-output ./MySDK.xcframework
```

I get the error:

```
The CodingKeys(stringValue: "SupportedPlatform", intValue: nil) is empty in library -arm64_armv7.
```

How can I create an XCFramework in this setting without an error?

Answer (score 1):

There was an extra library with .a extension for testing under Frameworks and Libraries section of the target and removing this library resolved the issue.